# SQL Query dealing with multiple "duplicate rows"

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got two tables:
users
user_licenses.
Their structure is as follows:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+
|             users table           |
+------------+-----------+----------+
| identifier | firstname | lastname |
+------------+-----------+----------+
|        122 | John      | Doe      |
|        123 | Johnny    | Dough    |
|        124 | Martin    | Pie      |
+------------+-----------+----------+

+------------+-----------+------------+
|         user_licenses table         |
+----+-------------+-------+----------+
| id |    type     | owner | warnings |
+----+-------------+-------+----------+
|  1 | drive       |   122 |        2 |
|  2 | drive_bike  |   122 |        2 |
|  3 | drive_truck |   123 |        3 |
|  4 | drive_bike  |   124 |        2 |
|  5 | drive       |   123 |        2 |
|  6 | drive_truck |   124 |        3 |
+----+-------------+-------+----------+
```

The thing is, I want to create a result that outputs the following:

```
identifier, firstname, lastname, typesOfLicenses(Commaseperated?), HowManyWarningsForEachLicense(Commaseperated?)
```

I don't know how to go about it:
I've tried joining the two in a query like this:

```
SELECT users.identifier, users.firstname, users.lastname, user_licenses.type, user_licenses.warnings FROM users INNER JOIN user_licenses ON users.identifier=user_licenses.owner;
```

But that creates multiple results for each person and their licenses.
I would like ONE result per person, and then their licenses combined into the types row (possibly commaseperated). How would I do this?

Comment: Format your code properly.  Don't just put it in one long line.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `group_concat` function with a `group by`.

Try this...

```
SELECT 
    users.identifier, 
    users.firstname, 
    users.lastname, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(user_licenses.type, ' - ', user_licenses.warnings) SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM users 
INNER JOIN user_licenses ON users.identifier=user_licenses.owner;
GROUP BY
    users.identifier, users.firstname, users.lastname
```

Comment: Hi, looks correct but I think only `GROUP BY users.identifier` why the 2 other grouping columns?

Comment: It's usually considered good practice to list all columns in the select statement in a group by if not being used in an aggregate. Microsoft SQL will throw an error if you don't. MySQL will let you get away without listing all columns, but *might* produce unexpected results sometimes

Comment: Oh I see, also I think there is a Mysql configuration option which make Mysql throws an error if you don't use them, good point.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much. This taught me a lot actually, about concatting and how it works. Appreciate the swift response!

Comment: "also I think there is a Mysql configuration option which make Mysql throws an error if you don't use them" Yes there is but if you don't have access to the config option use `SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode. ',only_full_group_by')`

Answer (score 0):

try this way,

```
SELECT users.identifier, users.firstname, users.lastname, 
    GROUP_CONCAT( TRIM( user_licenses.type ) ) AS typesOfLicenses, 
    GROUP_CONCAT( TRIM( user_licenses.warnings ) ) AS warningOfLicenses
FROM users
INNER JOIN user_licenses ON (users.identifier = user_licenses.owner)
GROUP BY users.identifier, users.firstname, users.lastname
```

it will work pretty well if user_licenses.warnings is a characters column.